# Data doesn't match to original data after converting to TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow

> **TL: DR;**

After converting my data to TFRecord it doesn't match with original data

> **Description:**

I made a [method](https://gist.github.com/niyamatalmass/b4e8f14d0a853b109035cc0973c03189) that will read TFRecord data. And I want to test that method that the method is working as I expected. So I create a [Tensorflow test case](https://gist.github.com/niyamatalmass/160207d687cd07d20bede12d8092f429) where I create a fake TFRecord file given some random input data. And pass that data to that method. The results get from that method and the original data, I pass them to the assertAllEqual() method for unit testing. But the test failed.

Here is test error

```
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not equal

(mismatch 66.66666666666666%)
x: array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],...
y: array([[[  0,   0,   0],
    [  0,   0,   0],
    [  0,   0,   0],...

not equal where =  (array([10, 10, 10, ..., 31, 31, 31]), array([21, 21, 22, ..., 31, 31, 31]), array([1, 2, 0, ..., 0, 1, 2]))
not equal lhs =  [128 128 128 ..., 255 255 255]
not equal rhs =  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
```

*Shape of the fake data (3, 32, 32, 3)*

> **Tried Solutions:**

1. Tried different input
2. Tried RandomSuffleQueue instead of FIFOQueue
3. **Check if test on labels is pass or not. Yes! test on labels passed!**

> **My Question:**

1. What's going wrong?
2. Is there any problem in the first method that is used for reading TFRecord file?
3. Am I doing anything wrong in my test case?

Answer (score 0):

> I found the solutions. The problem is in my test case where I made my
>   fake data for testing purpose. **The generation of fake data is wrong.**

I changed my code from this

```
records = [self._record(0, 128, 255),
               self._record(255, 0, 1),
               self._record(254, 255, 0)]
```

to this

```
    image_array_1 = np.random.random((32, 32, 3))
    image_array_2 = np.random.random((32, 32, 3))
    image_array_3 = np.random.random((32, 32, 3))

    formatted1 = (image_array_1 * 255 / np.max(image_array_1)).astype('uint8')
    formatted2 = (image_array_2 * 255 / np.max(image_array_2)).astype('uint8')
    formatted3 = (image_array_3 * 255 / np.max(image_array_3)).astype('uint8')
    images_data_set = [formatted1, formatted2, formatted3]
```

And the test passed perfectly!